# running pip install gives me Trace/BPT trap: 5 errror

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, homebrew

I see a lot of questions here having to with `Trace/BPT trap: 5` errors, but I haven't come across a solution.

The problem is: whenever I run `pip install <some_package>` I get a `Trace/BPT trap: 5` error.

From what I read so far, this has to do with dylibs that can not be found/loaded. However, I don't know how to solve that.

I do have `homebrew` installed, which somehow seems to be related to this problem, but I did NOT install python with homebrew:

```
$ ls -la $(which python)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66576 15 jul  2017 /usr/bin/python

$ ls -la $(which pip)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  290  1 apr 14:47 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

My Python version is Python 2.7.10, and I am on MacOS X 10.12.6 (Sierra) .

Again, my apologies if this is a duplicate. If someone could point me to the right post, in that case, I would appreciate it...

Comment: could you show the result of `head -n2 /usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Thanks! Sure:

`$ head -2 /usr/local/bin/pip`

`#!/usr/bin/python`
 `# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==10.0.0b1','console_scripts','pip'`

And what does this tell us?

Comment: just want to make sure your pip info, it looks fine. I've tried on my macos to install pip using `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip` and then tried to install some package, `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install ipython`, it works fine too. Sorry could not reproduce the situation you met.

Comment: OK, too bad. I am pretty stuck as to where to look for solutions to be honest. But anyway, thanks for checking!